# Find radius of the circle analytically

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

Given the circle as seen in the attached image, find the radius of the circle **analytically**. Is that even possible? I know it can be found numerically. If analytical solution does not exist, can you also provide some hint why not?

If it's not clear: You only know $c$ and $s$.

[image: circle]

Comment: $\theta=180$ isn't it

Comment: What angle do you mean by $theta$ ?

Comment: I do not know whether this will help, but if $\theta$ is the central angle subtended by the chord, then $c = 2r\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$ and $s = 2\pi r - r\theta$.

Comment: We have also to consider, on which "side" the arc lies, Does the figure above contain the mid-point of the circle or not ? I am not sure whether this can be decided only knowing $c$ and $s$, but probably it can.

Comment: @Peter Whatever side you want... In either way I get strangled in equation that can't be solved analytically.

Comment: Is $r$ uniquely determined by $c$ and $s$ ? It is not obvious for me.

Comment: I don't know, to be honest. In this link (http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.circle.segment.html#n1) it sure looks like it's unique, is it not?

Comment: Taussig's equations probably do not allow a closed-form-solution.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the depicted configuration, $c=2R\sin\theta$ and $s=2R(\pi-\theta)$. Let $\varphi=\pi-\theta$ and $k=\frac{c}{s}$.

Given $c$ and $s$, in order to find $\varphi$ we have to solve $\frac{\sin \varphi}{\varphi} = \frac{c}{s}$ or 
$$ \sin(\varphi) = k\cdot\varphi \tag{1}$$
that has a unique solution $\varphi\in (0,\pi)$ since the sine function is concave over that interval and its derivative is bounded by one in absolute value. $(1)$ has no explicit solution, but [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) is very effective in finding an approximate solution. A good starting point for Newton's method can be the solution of the approximate equation:
$$ \frac{4}{\pi^2}\varphi(\pi-\varphi) = k\cdot \varphi, \tag{2}$$
i.e. $\displaystyle\varphi_0 = \frac{\pi(4-k\pi)}{4}$.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, but I'm still waiting for analytical solution or explanation why there isn't one. I'll wait some more...